# Why does Go keep creating `~/go` folder for its cache?

Tags: go

Go seems to create a folder `~/go` with a folder `pkg/mod` inside. Deleting this folder simply leads to it being recreated as Go is run in due course.

Does anyone know how to set the Go environment such that this folder resides elsewhere? My `go env` shows the following line for `$GOCACHE` & `$GOMODCACHE`:

```
...
GOCACHE="~/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOMODCACHE="~/Library/gocode/pkg/mod"
...
```

(I've replaced the `/User/<user name>/` bit here with `~/`.)

There's no sign of the `~/go` folder in either of them, so I'm lost as to how to redirect it.

I have Go version `go version go1.19.5 darwin/arm64` on macOS Ventura.

Comment: There is also a `GOCACHE` environment variable, though this should already default to being inside your Library. If you run `go env | grep -i "cache"` what do you see?

Comment: Go only creates the path when it's written to, so figure out what exactly which command is creating it, and carefully check the environment and version for that command. Otherwise create a [mre] because that should work as expected.

Comment: @Adrian I've updated the question and listed `$GOCACHE` line too.